# Longtable fail to break the page with landscape, siunitx and threepartTable

Tags: longtable, siunitx, landscape, threeparttable

The table I have is too wide and long, so I decide to use landscape with longtable to display the table. However, with a lot of search, I have no luck in making the table to break into two pages with longtable. I found one [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101830/struggling-with-landscape-longtable-threeparttable) in this forum, but I didn't get any hints why my example would be fail even I am not using table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=0.05cm, hmargin=0.1cm, marginparwidth=0.1cm,total={210mm,297mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, xcolor}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage{longtable}


\newlength{\mylength} \settowidth{\mylength}{$-55.55\pm0.55$}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\notsotiny{\@setfontsize\notsotiny{6.5}{7.5}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\sisetup{
    table-number-alignment=center,
    separate-uncertainty=true,
    table-format =-2.2,
    separate-uncertainty,
    table-figures-uncertainty=1, table-space-text-post=(16)}
\begin{threeparttable} % <--- new
\notsotiny
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{longtable}{>{\itshape}l@{}c*{12}{S}@{}}%
        \caption{Taxon}\\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Site} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SL} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EI} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-14}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Season}& {Wet} &{Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {\makebox[\mylength]{Dry}} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Species}}   & Tracer & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{14}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Site} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SL} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EI} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-14}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Season}& {Wet} &{Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {\makebox[\mylength]{Dry}} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Species}}   & Tracer & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead

\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       & 12.23\pm0.37\ts{(2)} & 11.32\ts{(1)} &       & 11.71\pm1.39\ts{(2)} & 12.07\pm0.20\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       & -15.65\pm0.60\ts{(2)} & -16.07\ts{(1)} &       & -15.46\pm0.68\ts{(2)} & -15.63\pm0.18\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 15.42\pm1.26\ts{(8)} & 13.71\pm0.82\ts{(8)} &       & 14.90\pm1.14\ts{(8)} & 16.43\pm2.17\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -20.57\pm1.14\ts{(8)} & -17.80\pm1.53\ts{(8)} &       & -18.93\pm0.84\ts{(8)} & -19.22\pm2.20\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 12.41\pm0.31\ts{(4)} &       & 12.12\pm0.79\ts{(4)} & 12.10\pm0.10\ts{(3)} \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & -15.84\pm0.42\ts{(4)} &       & -16.23\pm0.34\ts{(4)} & -16.77\pm0.12\ts{(3)} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 12.70\pm0.28\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & -15.80\pm0.14\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 14.32\pm0.94\ts{(17)} & 12.86\pm0.71\ts{(16)} & 12.74\pm1.03\ts{(16)} & 12.36\pm0.41\ts{(16)} & 12.45\pm0.83\ts{(12)} & 12.72\pm0.46\ts{(15)} & 12.02\pm0.67\ts{(14)} & 12.88\pm0.25\ts{(12)} & 13.08\pm0.89\ts{(16)} & 14.45\pm0.35\ts{(8)} & 13.80\pm0.50\ts{(10)} &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.51\pm0.49\ts{(17)} & -16.86\pm0.83\ts{(16)} & -16.65\pm0.38\ts{(16)} & -15.76\pm0.34\ts{(16)} & -16.19\pm0.59\ts{(12)} & -15.45\pm0.29\ts{(15)} & -16.32\pm0.42\ts{(14)} & -15.74\pm0.28\ts{(12)} & -16.09\pm0.40\ts{(16)} & -15.97\pm0.27\ts{(8)} & -15.97\pm0.40\ts{(10)} &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 14.90\pm1.51\ts{(6)} & 14.59\pm1.39\ts{(4)} &       &       & 12.70\ts{(1)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -18.13\pm0.48\ts{(6)} & -18.07\pm2.07\ts{(4)} &       &       & -15.91\ts{(1)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 13.41\pm0.21\ts{(4)} & 13.47\pm0.56\ts{(4)} & 13.33\pm0.43\ts{(3)} &       & 11.78\pm0.24\ts{(8)} & 12.00\pm0.20\ts{(4)} & 11.77\pm0.28\ts{(8)} & 12.62\pm0.24\ts{(8)} & 13.37\pm0.21\ts{(2)} &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.79\pm0.12\ts{(4)} & -17.57\pm0.16\ts{(4)} & -16.92\pm0.71\ts{(3)} &       & -16.21\pm0.14\ts{(8)} & -15.97\pm0.17\ts{(4)} & -16.13\pm0.15\ts{(8)} & -15.87\pm0.13\ts{(8)} & -16.47\pm0.09\ts{(2)} &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       & 12.27\pm0.26\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       & -15.60\pm0.06\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 13.70\ts{(1)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 14.17\pm0.38\ts{(3)} &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -16.24\ts{(1)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & -15.93\pm0.06\ts{(3)} &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 13.02\pm0.42\ts{(4)} & 12.34\pm0.40\ts{(4)} & 12.61\pm0.25\ts{(4)} & 12.03\pm0.17\ts{(4)} & 11.63\pm0.48\ts{(8)} & 12.36\pm0.18\ts{(7)} & 11.69\pm0.42\ts{(8)} & 12.76\pm0.29\ts{(8)} &       &       & 12.97\pm0.08\ts{(2)} &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.99\pm0.35\ts{(4)} & -17.48\pm0.13\ts{(4)} & -16.60\pm0.16\ts{(4)} & -16.27\pm0.09\ts{(4)} & -16.23\pm0.30\ts{(8)} & -16.26\pm0.08\ts{(7)} & -16.15\pm0.15\ts{(8)} & -16.29\pm0.06\ts{(8)} &       &       & -16.05\pm0.13\ts{(2)} &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 12.96\pm2.30\ts{(7)} & 12.73\pm0.65\ts{(4)} &       & 12.08\pm0.52\ts{(4)} & 11.88\pm0.66\ts{(8)} & 12.12\pm0.18\ts{(8)} & 11.79\pm0.37\ts{(8)} & 12.29\pm0.27\ts{(8)} & 12.18\pm0.19\ts{(4)} &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.98\pm0.51\ts{(7)} & -17.06\pm0.11\ts{(4)} &       & -16.31\pm0.22\ts{(4)} & -16.19\pm0.13\ts{(8)} & -15.96\pm0.09\ts{(8)} & -16.25\pm0.12\ts{(8)} & -16.24\pm0.11\ts{(8)} & -16.36\pm0.07\ts{(4)} &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 12.91\pm0.37\ts{(4)} & 11.97\pm0.47\ts{(8)} & 12.48\pm0.36\ts{(8)} & 11.87\pm0.25\ts{(8)} & 11.42\pm0.43\ts{(7)} &       & 11.75\pm0.21\ts{(8)} &       & 13.15\pm0.42\ts{(2)} &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -18.97\pm0.35\ts{(4)} & -17.08\pm0.17\ts{(8)} & -17.02\pm0.30\ts{(8)} & -15.79\pm0.12\ts{(8)} & -15.88\pm0.14\ts{(7)} &       & -16.07\pm0.23\ts{(8)} &       & -15.89\pm0.44\ts{(2)} &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 12.82\pm0.65\ts{(2)} & 11.56\pm1.04\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.80\pm0.19\ts{(2)} & -17.71\pm1.12\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       & 13.43\pm1.72\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       & -17.22\pm0.57\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       & 12.31\pm1.34\ts{(7)} & 12.72\pm1.34\ts{(8)} &       & 12.19\pm0.53\ts{(8)} & 11.98\pm0.15\ts{(2)} & 11.53\pm0.20\ts{(8)} & 12.63\pm0.02\ts{(2)} & 12.27\pm0.37\ts{(8)} & 13.40\pm0.29\ts{(8)} & 12.18\pm0.60\ts{(8)} & 13.03\pm0.13\ts{(3)} \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       & -17.42\pm1.05\ts{(7)} & -16.08\pm0.25\ts{(8)} &       & -16.32\pm0.16\ts{(8)} & -16.16\pm0.15\ts{(2)} & -16.26\pm0.12\ts{(8)} & -16.38\pm0.06\ts{(2)} & -16.66\pm0.39\ts{(8)} & -17.00\pm0.18\ts{(8)} & -16.80\pm0.27\ts{(8)} & -17.08\pm0.19\ts{(3)} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 12.26\pm1.34\ts{(8)} &       & 12.07\pm0.31\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -18.08\pm0.54\ts{(8)} &       & -16.70\pm1.76\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 13.82\pm1.89\ts{(2)} & 14.48\pm0.31\ts{(4)} & 13.32\pm0.73\ts{(8)} & 11.62\pm0.16\ts{(2)} & 12.49\pm0.41\ts{(4)} & 11.92\pm0.31\ts{(7)} & 11.33\pm0.43\ts{(3)} & 12.21\pm0.17\ts{(6)} & 13.13\pm0.26\ts{(8)} &       & 12.17\pm0.40\ts{(8)} &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.50\pm0.11\ts{(2)} & -16.95\pm0.17\ts{(4)} & -16.64\pm0.17\ts{(8)} & -15.66\pm0.16\ts{(2)} & -16.34\pm0.16\ts{(4)} & -15.71\pm0.41\ts{(7)} & -16.08\pm0.06\ts{(3)} & -16.01\pm0.28\ts{(6)} & -16.04\pm0.17\ts{(8)} &       & -15.28\pm0.37\ts{(8)} &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 13.29\pm1.45\ts{(8)} & 12.93\pm0.41\ts{(8)} & 12.97\pm0.32\ts{(8)} & 13.28\pm2.79\ts{(4)} & 12.41\pm0.29\ts{(8)} & 12.39\pm0.03\ts{(2)} & 11.67\pm0.47\ts{(7)} &       & 13.03\pm0.68\ts{(8)} & 13.97\pm0.06\ts{(3)} &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.56\pm0.34\ts{(8)} & -17.14\pm0.31\ts{(8)} & -16.33\pm0.38\ts{(8)} & -15.59\pm0.36\ts{(4)} & -16.25\pm0.25\ts{(8)} & -15.33\pm0.01\ts{(2)} & -16.10\pm0.30\ts{(7)} &       & -15.49\pm1.16\ts{(8)} & -15.80\pm0.26\ts{(3)} &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 12.90\pm1.31\ts{(8)} & 13.02\pm0.42\ts{(4)} & 12.84\pm0.23\ts{(2)} & 12.29\pm0.03\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.04\pm1.11\ts{(8)} & -16.44\pm0.14\ts{(4)} & -15.69\pm0.03\ts{(2)} & -15.51\pm0.06\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       & 11.81\pm0.56\ts{(4)} &       &       &       &       &       & 12.44\pm0.27\ts{(2)} &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       & -17.53\pm0.29\ts{(4)} &       &       &       &       &       & -16.63\pm0.09\ts{(2)} &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 12.60\pm0.19\ts{(2)} &       &       &       & 13.59\pm0.23\ts{(2)} &       & 12.04\pm0.82\ts{(2)} &       & 14.17\pm0.83\ts{(3)} &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -16.85\pm1.20\ts{(2)} &       &       &       & -15.96\pm0.63\ts{(2)} &       & -16.07\pm0.76\ts{(2)} &       & -15.48\pm0.64\ts{(3)} &       &       &  \\

\newpage
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       & 11.73\pm0.18\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       & -14.88\pm0.78\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       & 14.31\ts{(1)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       & -16.24\ts{(1)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       & 10.85\pm0.16\ts{(4)} & 11.71\ts{(1)} &       &       & 13.16\ts{(1)} &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       & -16.08\pm0.12\ts{(4)} & -15.90\ts{(1)} &       &       & -16.54\ts{(1)} &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 14.26\pm2.06\ts{(8)} &       & 13.15\pm1.43\ts{(8)} & 12.83\pm0.75\ts{(3)} & 12.82\pm0.77\ts{(8)} &       & 12.26\pm0.47\ts{(8)} &       & 13.22\pm1.02\ts{(4)} &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.29\pm3.48\ts{(8)} &       & -17.20\pm0.54\ts{(8)} & -15.90\pm0.12\ts{(3)} & -16.66\pm0.51\ts{(8)} &       & -15.52\pm2.48\ts{(8)} &       & -16.49\pm0.48\ts{(4)} &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       &       & 12.23\pm0.35\ts{(6)} & 13.02\pm0.30\ts{(8)} &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       &       & -16.25\pm0.08\ts{(6)} & -16.35\pm0.11\ts{(8)} &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 13.17\pm0.41\ts{(8)} & 12.80\pm0.41\ts{(4)} & 13.30\pm0.20\ts{(6)} & 13.03\pm0.26\ts{(4)} \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & -16.46\pm0.26\ts{(8)} & -16.70\pm0.22\ts{(4)} & -16.26\pm0.17\ts{(6)} & -16.85\pm0.24\ts{(4)} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       &       & 12.16\pm0.61\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       &       & -15.72\pm0.03\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &  \\
      \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 14.36\pm0.62\ts{(3)} & 11.96\pm0.39\ts{(4)} &       &       & 12.09\pm0.52\ts{(4)} & 12.57\pm0.16\ts{(4)} & 12.39\pm0.18\ts{(4)} &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.79\pm0.37\ts{(3)} & -16.85\pm0.09\ts{(4)} &       &       & -15.77\pm0.07\ts{(4)} & -15.55\pm0.20\ts{(4)} & -15.82\pm0.19\ts{(4)} &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 12.53\pm0.94\ts{(4)} &       & 11.80\pm0.29\ts{(3)} & 11.36\pm0.61\ts{(2)} & 12.28\pm0.80\ts{(4)} &       & 10.47\pm2.37\ts{(4)} &       & 12.43\pm0.20\ts{(4)} & 12.59\pm0.55\ts{(8)} & 12.06\pm0.17\ts{(4)} & 12.18\pm0.15\ts{(4)} \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -18.30\pm0.74\ts{(4)} &       & -15.26\pm0.53\ts{(3)} & -15.43\pm0.23\ts{(2)} & -16.63\pm1.42\ts{(4)} &       & -16.03\pm0.76\ts{(4)} &       & -15.04\pm0.21\ts{(4)} & -16.07\pm0.58\ts{(8)} & -15.35\pm0.33\ts{(4)} & -16.32\pm0.43\ts{(4)} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 14.13\pm1.15\ts{(16)} & 12.90\pm0.42\ts{(17)} & 13.17\pm1.36\ts{(16)} &       & 11.98\pm0.67\ts{(16)} & 12.89\pm0.38\ts{(15)} & 12.28\pm0.42\ts{(16)} & 13.36\pm0.29\ts{(16)} & 13.32\pm0.69\ts{(3)} & 13.31\pm0.39\ts{(12)} &       & 13.12\pm0.31\ts{(9)} \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.88\pm0.74\ts{(16)} & -16.70\pm0.44\ts{(17)} & -17.46\pm0.68\ts{(16)} &       & -16.50\pm0.23\ts{(16)} & -16.22\pm0.24\ts{(15)} & -16.46\pm0.17\ts{(16)} & -16.26\pm0.18\ts{(16)} & -16.53\pm0.20\ts{(3)} & -16.77\pm0.14\ts{(12)} &       & -16.83\pm0.29\ts{(9)} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 11.35\ts{(1)} &       & 12.53\pm0.93\ts{(13)} & 12.58\pm0.51\ts{(12)} & 12.61\pm0.48\ts{(5)} & 12.36\pm0.74\ts{(10)} & 12.31\pm0.68\ts{(10)} & 12.00\pm1.13\ts{(2)} & 13.05\pm0.51\ts{(16)} & 14.10\pm0.25\ts{(8)} & 12.63\pm0.63\ts{(2)} & 13.73\pm0.66\ts{(3)} \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -16.29\ts{(1)} &       & -16.21\pm0.21\ts{(13)} & -15.78\pm0.67\ts{(12)} & -16.09\pm0.70\ts{(5)} & -15.24\pm0.40\ts{(10)} & -16.07\pm0.40\ts{(10)} & -16.58\pm1.85\ts{(2)} & -15.73\pm0.78\ts{(16)} & -15.97\pm0.14\ts{(8)} & -16.20\pm0.26\ts{(2)} & -15.87\pm0.24\ts{(3)} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 14.18\pm0.23\ts{(4)} & 13.64\pm0.53\ts{(4)} &       &       & 12.28\pm0.05\ts{(4)} & 11.62\pm0.05\ts{(4)} & 11.75\pm0.10\ts{(4)} & 11.50\pm0.27\ts{(4)} & 13.38\pm0.17\ts{(4)} &       & 13.41\pm0.17\ts{(2)} &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -16.34\pm0.13\ts{(4)} & -16.36\pm0.20\ts{(4)} &       &       & -15.51\pm0.10\ts{(4)} & -15.93\pm0.21\ts{(4)} & -15.74\pm0.18\ts{(4)} & -15.75\pm0.10\ts{(4)} & -15.84\pm0.14\ts{(4)} &       & -16.22\pm0.14\ts{(2)} &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 14.32\pm0.94\ts{(4)} &       &       & 12.45\pm0.26\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -16.64\pm0.43\ts{(4)} &       &       & -15.30\pm0.31\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 13.92\pm0.55\ts{(8)} & 12.28\pm0.61\ts{(8)} &       &       & 11.93\pm0.48\ts{(3)} &       &       &       & 13.59\pm0.16\ts{(2)} &       & 14.14\pm0.56\ts{(2)} &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -17.95\pm0.33\ts{(8)} & -17.35\pm0.41\ts{(8)} &       &       & -15.61\pm0.08\ts{(3)} &       &       &       & -16.01\pm0.02\ts{(2)} &       & -16.10\pm0.40\ts{(2)} &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       & 12.39\pm0.32\ts{(4)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       & -16.97\pm0.33\ts{(4)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N & 9.21\pm1.28\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C & -22.56\pm4.18\ts{(3)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}} & $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       & 9.67\pm0.62\ts{(4)} & 8.10\pm0.28\ts{(2)} & 11.20\pm0.07\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &  \\
      & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       & -16.58\pm0.32\ts{(4)} & -17.25\pm0.07\ts{(2)} & -16.21\pm0.19\ts{(2)} &       &       &       &       &  \\

        \bottomrule

    \end{longtable}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Threepartable is an unbreakable box, thus no page breaks. See the threeparttablex package for a slightly different approach

Comment: I have noticed the use of threeparttablex but I just find out that I overlooked the change of ThreePartTable to threeparttable in my code. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `threeparttable` environment is basically an unbreakable box designed for tables that fit inside a float. It will measure the size of the table and adjust the width of the environment to match that width.

Obviously this is bad for an environment like `longtable` where the whole premise is that it is breakable across pages.

We can instead use the `threeparttablex` package which extends `threeparttable` with the   `ThreePartTable` (this env doesn't actually do much, it is the `\insertTableNotes` that does the work) that goes around the `longtable` plus some special features to insert the table notes at the end of the `longtable` (but actually as a part of the `longtable`, and thus inheriting its width)

Here is the example code from the manual:

```
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[a] A note
\item[b] Another note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{l l}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endhead
\cmidrule{2-2}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{continued}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes % <--- note this
\endlastfoot
% the contents of the table
A
& B\tnote{a} \\
C\tnote{b} & D
\\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
```